# Match value in two files and replace values in selected columns

Tags: awk

The purpose is to check if values for column 3 and 4 in file1 match with column 1 in file2.
If any value match, then replace values in file2 for column 2 and 3 using the information of file1 columns 5 and 6

Also, I need add the values of columns 7 and 8 from file1 into file2 in columns 1 and 2 for the matched lines, and character R for lines replaced and O for lines not replaced,

**file1**

```
2,100,31431,37131,999991.70,0000000.30,11111,22222,3
3,100,31431,37471,111113.20,1111111.30,22222,33333,4
```

**file2**

```
3143137113 318512.50 2334387.50 100
3143137131 318737.50 2334387.50 100
3143137201 319612.50 2334387.50 100
3143137471 322987.50 2334387.50 100
3143137491 323237.50 2334387.50 100
```

**Desired output:**

```
31431,37113,318512.50,2334387.50,100,O
11111,22222,999991.70,0000000.30,100,R
31431,37201,319612.50,2334387.50,100,O
22222,33333,111113.20,1111111.30,100,R
31431,37491,323237.50,2334387.50,100,O
```

**I tried these 2:**

1)

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  OFS=","
}
FNR==NR{
  a[$3 $4]=$3 OFS $4
  b[$3 $4]=$5
  c[$3 $4]=$6
  d[$3 $4]=$7 OFS $8
  next
}
($1 in
 a){
  $4=d[$1]
  $3=c[$1]
  $2=b[$1]
  $1=a[$1]
  print
  next
}
{
  $1=$1
  sub(/^...../,"&,",$1)
  print
}
' FS=","  file1 FS=" "  file2
```

**output**

```
31431,37113,318512.50,2334387.50,100
31431,37131,999991.70,0000000.30,11111,22222
31431,37201,319612.50,2334387.50,100
31431,37471,111113.20,1111111.30,22222,33333
31431,37491,323237.50,2334387.50,100
```

2)

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$3 $4]=substr($0,length($3 FS)+1);next} $1 in a{print a[$1],$NF;next} {$1=substr($1,1,5) OFS substr($1,6,5);} 1' OFS=, file1 FS=' ' file2
```

**output**

```
31431,37113,318512.50,2334387.50,100
31431,37131,999991.70,0000000.30,11111,22222,3,100
31431,37201,319612.50,2334387.50,100
31431,37471,111113.20,1111111.30,22222,33333,4,100
31431,37491,323237.50,2334387.50,100
```

Both works, but not completely.

Thanks in advance

Comment: is Perl solution fine for you?

Comment: @OXXO, please DO NOT change your requirements frequently, it is 3rd or 4th time I had to change my code(after your question changes). It will make people think that our codes are NOT working and they may even get confuse. Simply give 3 things. 1st- your sample of Input, 2nd- your sample of expected output and 3rd- what you tried(which you are giving already). Request you to do not change question frequently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[$3 $4]=$7 $8
  b[$3 $4]=$5
  c[$3 $4]=$6
  next
}
($1 in a){
  $2=b[$1]
  $3=c[$1]
  $1=a[$1]
  found=1
}
{
  $0=found==1?$0",R":$0",O"
  sub(/^...../,"&,")
  $1=$1
  found=""
}
1
' FS="," file1 FS=" " OFS="," file2
```

Output will be as follows.

```
31431,37113,318512.50,2334387.50,100,O
11111,22222,999991.70,0000000.30,100,R
31431,37201,319612.50,2334387.50,100,O
22222,33333,111113.20,1111111.30,100,R
31431,37491,323237.50,2334387.50,100,O
```

Comment: Ravinder, tks a lot for the code,, Sorry i have modified a little the desired output, Kindly can you please update the code,,,

Comment: @OXXO, please DO NOT change your requirements frequently, it is 3rd or 4th time I had to change my code. It will make people think that my code is NOT producing proper output, so please DO NOT change your questions after posting. kindly check this and let me know now?

Comment: Ravinder.. Very Sorry for the change. many thanks for your help . I will follow ur advise

Comment: @OXXO, you need not to be sorry buddy, just take it easy we all are here to learn and guide each other. But yes keep question un-changed to be very honest else it may confuse people around here. Keep learning and keep sharing on this GREAT site SO.

Comment: Ravinder..tks a lot .. Will follow your advise. Tks again

Answer (score 2):

Perl version:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use autodie;
use feature qw/say/;

my ($file1, $file2) = @ARGV;
my %rows;

open my $f1, '<', $file1;
while (<$f1>) {
  chomp;
  my @F = split /,/;
  $rows{"$F[2]$F[3]"} = \@F;
}

open my $f2, '<', $file2;
$, = ','; # Like awk OFS
while (<$f2>) {
  chomp;
  my @F = split;
  if (exists $rows{$F[0]}) {
    my $left = $rows{$F[0]};
    say @{$left}[2..5], $F[3], @{$left}[6,7]; 
  } else {
    my ($col1, $col2) = $F[0] =~ m/^(.{5})(.{5})$/;
    say $col1, $col2, @F[1..3];
  }
}
```

Example:

```
$ ./example.pl file1.csv file2.txt
31431,37113,318512.50,2334387.50,100
31431,37131,999991.70,0000000.30,100,11111,22222
31431,37201,319612.50,2334387.50,100
31431,37471,111113.20,1111111.30,100,22222,33333
31431,37491,323237.50,2334387.50,100
```

Comment: Shawn, tks a lot for the code,, Sorry i have modified a little the output desired, can you please update the code,,,